# PHP RegEx and parts of string

Tags: php, regex

I have strings, for example:

```
bool dxDrawImage float posX, float posY, float width, float height, mixed image , float rotation = 0, float rotationCenterOffsetX = 0, float rotationCenterOffsetY = 0, int color = white, bool postGUI = false
bool dxUpdateScreenSource element screenSource, bool resampleNow =false
```

I need get parts from it, for example:

```
bool dxDrawImage
float posX
float posY
...
```

I wrote:

```
preg_match_all("/(bool|float|int)[a-zA-Z0-9\s=]+/", $txt, $ar);
```

print_r($ar):

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => bool dxDrawImage float posX [1] => float posY [2] => float width [3] => float height [4] => float rotation = 0 [5] => float rotationCenterOffsetX = 0 [6] => float rotationCenterOffsetY = 0 [7] => int color = white [8] => bool postGUI = false ) [1] => Array ( [0] => bool [1] => float [2] => float [3] => float [4] => float [5] => float [6] => float [7] => int [8] => bool ) )
```

Why this regexp capture `bool dxDrawImage float posX` instead

```
bool dxDrawImage
float posX
```

How to fix this?

Comment: hmm, is it ok that  ther no comma between `bool dxDrawImage` and  `float posX` in input string?

Comment: Oh, of course. I forgot that there is separator between other parts of string...
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match_all("/(\b(?:bool|float|int|element)\s+.*?)(?=\b(?:bool|float|int|element|[,;\n\r]|$))/", $txt, $ar); 
print_r($ar[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may disallow whitespaces in variable name:

```
preg_match_all("/(bool|float|int)\s+[a-zA-Z0-9=]+/", $txt, $ar);
```

What if you will use:

```
preg_match_all("/(bool|float|int)\s+[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\s+=\s+[chars,possible for value]+)?/", $txt, $ar);
```

Comment: But, this
float rotationCenterOffsetX = 0
wouldn't be captured.

Comment: Although I can replace this by making, for example, float rotationCenterOffsetX=0, but I need spaces between equals sign.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the *ungreedy* flag.

```
preg_match_all("/(bool|float|int)[a-zA-Z0-9\s=]+/U", $txt, $ar);
```

Comment: AFAIK, It will match only `bool`, `float` or `int`

Comment: Warning: preg_match_all() expects parameter 4 to be long, string given

Answer (score 0):

The part that delimits one variable from the other is a bit unclear in your string. That makes it a bit hard to separate each from another. However, you can relatively simple still write the pattern as it occurs:

```
((?:bool|float|mixed|int|element) [a-zA-Z]+(?: = ?[a-z0-9]+)?)(?:\s?,\s?|\s|$)
|^-------- variable type -------^     |    ^--- optional ---^|^-- delimiter -^
|                                   name                     |
|                                                            |
`------------------ the interesting part --------------------´
```

Such a pattern works with `preg_match_all`:

```
$pattern = '(((?:bool|float|mixed|int|element) [a-zA-Z]+(?: = ?[a-z0-9]+)?)(?:\s?,\s?|\s|$))';
$variables = array();
if ($r = preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches)) {
    $variables = $matches[1];
}
print_r($variables);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => bool dxDrawImage
    [1] => float posX
    [2] => float posY
    [3] => float width
    [4] => float height
    [5] => mixed image
    [6] => float rotation = 0
    [7] => float rotationCenterOffsetX = 0
    [8] => float rotationCenterOffsetY = 0
    [9] => int color = white
    [10] => bool postGUI = false
    [11] => bool dxUpdateScreenSource
    [12] => element screenSource
    [13] => bool resampleNow =false
)
```

The other alternative is to only use the delimiter and split the string. However after the delimiter a variable type plus space follows (look-ahead):

```
$pattern = '((?:\s?,\s?|\s)(?=(?:bool|float|mixed|int|element)))';
$variables = preg_split($pattern, $subject);
print_r($variables);
```

It gives you the same result as above.